# Using a query as a table to count column instances

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to databases and I'm attempting to return a count of instances in a certain column in a table that's created from a JOIN query. The query is this:

```
SELECT B.building, E.energytype
FROM Buildings b
LEFT JOIN build_types bt ON B.build_ID = bt.build_ID
LEFT JOIN EnergyTypes e ON bt.type_ID = E.type_ID
ORDER BY B.building;
```

I want to count how many times each energy type shows up in this table, and display a table that has energy type on the left and count on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `group by` and `count` aggregate function:

```
SELECT E.energytype, COUNT(*)
FROM Buildings b
JOIN build_types bt ON B.build_ID = bt.build_ID
JOIN EnergyTypes e ON bt.type_ID = E.type_ID
GROUP BY E.energytype;
```

BTW, is there really a point in using `left join` instead of `inner join` (it seems like these fields are foreign keys)?

Comment: Your solution worked. I also changed join to inner join in my original query. Can you tell me how you knew that these fields are foreign keys? I'm having a bit of trouble with that concept.

Comment: Well, it just seemed like that (according to table and column names).